# JSF: ajax not working for nested datalist

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, nested-datalist

I have an ul orderlist multiple list items and the last list item contains a dropdown of different shipping options.

```
<ul class="shipping_group">
    <p:dataList id="cartOrderItemList" rendered="#{ not empty cart.cartSummary.orderItems}"
        type="none" var="orderItem" value="#{cart.cartSummary.orderItems}">
    <li>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="finishing"></div>
        <div class="qty"></div>
        <div class="item_subtotal"></div>
    </li>
    </p:dataList>
    <li>
        <div class="shipping_method">
            <p>These items will ship together. Choose Shipping Method:</p>
            <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="shipping_select" value="#{cart.cartSummary.shippingMethod}">  
                <f:selectItems value="#{cart.cartSummary.shippings}" var="rate" itemValue="#{rate.method}" itemLabel="#{rate.displayNameDesc}"/>  
                <p:ajax update="shippingMethodText shippingMethod2Text" listener="#{cart.updateShippingMethod}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </div>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

Somewhere in my code I have this:

```
<span class="shipping">Total Shipping Cost: <strong>
    <h:outputText id="shippingMethodText" value="#{cart.cartSummary.shippingPrice}">
    <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency" />
    </h:outputText></strong>
</span>
```

And the backing bean method:

```
Cart.java
private CartSummary cartSummary;
private List shippings
public void updateShippingMethod(){ .... }

CartSummary.java
private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
```

Here are the basic functionality:

1. Dropdown selection change
2. updateShippingMethod() will fired
3. shippingMethodText will get updated.

All good. Until...I nested the whole structure with another datalist.

```
<!-- Cart Group -->
<p:dataList id="cartGroupList" rendered="#{not empty cart.cartSummary.cartGroups}" type="none"
    var="group" value="#{cart.cartSummary.cartGroups}">
    <ul class="shipping_group">
        <p:dataList id="shipping_group" type="none" var="orderItem" value="#{group.orderItems}">
        <li>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="finishing"></div>
            <div class="qty"></div>
            <div class="item_subtotal"></div>
        </li>
        </p:dataList>
        <li>
            <div class="shipping_method">
                <p>These items will ship together. Choose Shipping Method:</p>
                <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="shipping_select" value="#{cart.cartSummary.shippingMethod}">  
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cart.cartSummary.shippings}" var="rate" itemValue="#{rate.method}" itemLabel="#{rate.displayNameDesc}"/>  
                    <p:ajax update="shippingMethodText" listener="#{cart.updateShippingMethod}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </div>  
        </li>
    </ul>
</p:dataList>
```

With the corresponding Backing beans change:

```
Cart.java
private CartSummary cartSummary;
public void updateShippingMethod(){ .... }

CartSummary.java
private List<CartGroup> cartGroups; 

CartGroup.java
private List<OrderItem> orderItems
private List shippings
```

The method in the listener has no change. Somehow, no js is triggered. I tried to debug in primefaces.js.jsf and jsf.js.jsf. But no breakpoints got hit. I am using primefaces 3.4 and glassfish faces 2.1.4

Which js files does JSF use for ajax functions? JSF is using the same selector as "plain" jquery, right? How does it find the selector and capture the event?

Thank you very much for any suggestions.